# Month wise task completed in minutes between two dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get month-wise minutes spent on any assigned task to an employee.

For example when I select date between 1-Jan-2021 to 1-Jan-2022 then it should give the number of minutes spent by each employee month-wise in minutes.
Suppose in a filter I select a fromdate 1-Jan-2021 to date 1-Jan-2022 then if task start on Task_start_date='2021-09-02 10:00:00.000' and end on Task_end_date='2021-12-02 14:00:00.000' then I should get month wise report in minutes spent by employee on this assigned task.

```
 FILTER Date: 1-Jan-2021 to 1-Jan-2022

 Task Date:
 Task_start_date='2021-09-02 10:00:00.000'
 Task_end_date='2021-12-02 14:00:00.000'

Result 
       Employee  SEP-2021    | OCT-2021 | NOV-2021 | DEC-2021 
        X        39720min    | 43200min | 41160min | 1700min
```

If any body knows the query please share.

Comment: use [datediff()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find the difference between 2 datetime

Comment: please also show how do you derived the figure `2000min` or `2350min` in the expected result

Comment: suppose Task_start_date='2021-09-02 10:00:00.000'  then  for this month task will end on '2021-09-31 00:00:00.000' of this month then the difference of these two time in minutes

Comment: So how do you get `2000min` only for the entire month of Sep ? By there way, there isn't a `31` for the month of Sept :- `2021-09-31` is not a valid date

Comment: @ChotaVlog, from `2021-09-02 10:00:00`  to `2021-10-01 00:00:00` equals to  41160 minutes.

Comment: so for September month select datediff(MINUTE,'2021-09-02 10:00:00.000','2021-09-30 10:00:00.000') then  result in minute is 39720 ,similary for next month 1Oct to 31oct , 1nov to 30 nov, 1 dec to Task_end_date='2021-12-02 14:00:00.000'

Comment: @Ahmed I need minutes for each task month wise . Suppose in a filter I select a fromdate 1-Jan-2021  to date 1-Jan-2022  then if task start on  Task_start_date='2021-09-02 10:00:00.000' and  end on ask_end_date='2021-12-02 14:00:00.000' then I should get month wise report in minutes spent by employee on this assigned task. Total how many minutes spent in each month

Comment: @ChotaVlog Ok, I got it. Is it ok to list the months in rows instead of columns?

Comment: @Ahmed ok I will pivot it

Comment: `SEP-2021 - 39720min` this is basically `datediff(minute, '2021-09-02 10:00', '2021-09-30 00:00')`. So you are excluding the last 24 hours of the month ?

Comment: And how do you get `42600min` for Oct ?

Comment: @Squirrel select datediff(MINUTE,'2021-10-01 00:00:00.000','2021-10-31 00:00:00.000')

Comment: Did you tried at all ?  That gives `43200` not `42600`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following recursive `CTE`:

```
with cte as 
(
    select empid,format(st,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') st,en from MyTable
    union all
    select empid,format(dateadd(month,1,st),'yyyy-MM-01 00:00'),en from cte
    where dateadd(month,1,st)<=en
),
cte2 as 
(
    select empid, format(cast(st as datetime),'yyyy-MM') as Months,
    st, coalesce(lead(st) over (order by empid,st),dateadd(day,1,en)) as endOfMonths
    from cte
 )

select empid, Months, DateDiff(Minute, st, DateAdd(Day,-1,endOfMonths))
from cte2
```

See a demo from [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ca7fc9047e9c21be755a8aa5de3c6951).

To illustrate how it works, check the following output from `select * from cte2`:
[image]

Comment: @ChotaVlog, it's calculated by `DateAdd(Day,-1,endOfMonths)`, I subtract one day from each end to get the 28,30,31

Comment: For November it will be 41760 not 41160, and for December it will be 2280 not 1700, right?